# What do I supply to "LifeCycleOwner" parameter on observe in Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-livedata, observer-pattern

I'm fairly new on the Android Room, which uses LiveData that I'm also not familiar with. I noticed that on the tutorials, the data returned is using `LiveData` wrapper, like this:

```
@Dao
interface PersonDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM person")
    fun getAll(): LiveData<List<Person>>
}
```

Then to read the data, I use this code:

```
class PersonListActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

    List<Person> personList = listOf()

    init {
        val db = RoomDatabase.getDatabaseInstance()
        db.personDao.getAll().observe(this, Observe<List<Person>> { data ->
            personList = data
        })
    }

}
```

The problem is the IDE raise error "type mismatch". Required: LifeCycleOwner. Found: PersonListActivity. I don't understand how the tutorials can casually supply "this" into the observe owner parameter. I've also tried to supply `context` and `applicationContext` into the owner parameter and it doesn't work.

After I examine the `LifeCycleOwner` class, I tried to add the LifeCycleOwner implementation. But then the class requires `getLifeCycle()` function to be implemented. So I'm back at zero.

```
class PersonListActivity: AppCompatActivity(), LifeCycleOwner {

    List<Person> personList = listOf()

    init {
        val db = RoomDatabase.getDatabaseInstance()
        db.personDao.getAll().observe(this, Observe<List<Person>> { data ->
            personList = data
        })
    }

    override fun getLifeCycle() {
        // what should I return here??????
    }

}
```

Why all the tutorials I read about LiveData don't mention anything at all about LifeCycleOwner? Am I using the wrong observe function here?

```
public abstract class LiveData<T> {
    ...
    @MainThread
    public void observe(@NonNull LifecycleOwner owner, @NonNull Observer<? super T> observer) { ... }
    ...
}
```

Comment: What version of `androidx.appcompat:appcompat` are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Since the version **1.1.0** (excluding the not-stable releases) of `androidx.appcompat:appcompat`, `AppCompatActivity` implements `LifecycleOwner` (see `ComponentActivity`). So you can use `this` when calling:

```
db.personDao.getAll().observe(this, Observe<List<Person>> { data ->
    personList = data
})
```

Without implementing anything else.

Furthermore, I would move those lines in `Activity.onCreate()`.

Comment: You're right. My appcompat was not on version 1.1.0. After I change it into 1.1.0, the error is gone. Thanks!